# SetCapture does not work and returns nullptr

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to capture the mouse for a windowed game to handle mouse input and everytime I try, it returns nullptr. What I am seeing on the window is a waiting cursor (blue circle).

Here is the code for Win32 window wrapper:

```
XWindow::XWindow(WCHAR* title, int width, int height)
{
     memcpy(m_szTitle, title, sizeof(title));
     m_width = width;
     m_height = height;
}

ATOM XWindow::MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32PROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = m_szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL XWindow::InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    m_hInst = hInstance; 
    m_hWnd = CreateWindowW(m_szWindowClass, m_szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, m_width, m_height, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!m_hWnd)
        return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK XWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
                case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
                default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

And this is the WinMain function:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE 
hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    XIllumin* pMainGameWindow = new XIllumin(L"X3DEngine", 800, 600);

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    if (LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, pMainGameWindow-
    >GetWindowTitle(), MAX_LOADSTRING) == 0)
    return FALSE;

    if (LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT1, pMainGameWindow-
    >GetWindowClass(), MAX_LOADSTRING) == 0)
    return FALSE;

    pMainGameWindow->MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    if (!pMainGameWindow->InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;

    if (SetCapture(pMainGameWindow->GetWindowHandle()) == nullptr)
    //  return FALSE;

    if (!pMainGameWindow->ParseInitFile("Config/GameInit.txt"))
    {
        pMainGameWindow->FAIL_MSG_BOX(L"Error loading init file.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    pMainGameWindow->InitGameObjects(" ");

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT1));

    MSG msg;

    while (1)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                 pMainGameWindow->CleanUp();
                 break;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (!pMainGameWindow->GameMain(" "))
            break;
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

I am not sure what exactly is wrong. I think it might be the window creation parameters for CreateWindowW(), but don't really know which to use.

EDIT: The input is supposed to be handled by the game window when I hover the mouse cursor on it, but I see a waiting cursor as soon as the window pops up and the cursor is over it. Not really sure what else to say on top of that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `SetCapture` returns a handle to the window previously captured the mouse. So it is OK for `SetCapture` to return `NULL` when mouse was not captured by some other window previously. "Wait" cursor has nothing to do with it.

Note that by commenting `//  return FALSE;` you change `if` scope to the following, potentially skipping config loading:

```
if (SetCapture(pMainGameWindow->GetWindowHandle()) == nullptr)
{
    //  return FALSE;

    if (!pMainGameWindow->ParseInitFile("Config/GameInit.txt"))
    {
        pMainGameWindow->FAIL_MSG_BOX(L"Error loading init file.");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is a good example of why `{}` should never be omitted.

You should pump messages prior to calling `SetCapture` so window would be initialized and get to foreground propertly:

```
// at InitInstance
UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);
MSG msg;
while(PeekMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
       TranslateMessage(&msg);
       DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
```

Comment: OK. I commented out the return FALSE because I did not want the window to be closed. It was just a test. But the input is still not handled by the game window.

Comment: @Hermetix You may also need to pump window messages after showing window. `SetCapture` can only be called by foreground windows, while your window might not yet become foreground until you process some remaining initialization messages. You can check this by calling `GetForegroundWindow() == pMainGameWindow->GetWindowHandle()` before trying to capture input.

Comment: Just checked and GetForegroundWindow() != pMainGameWindow->GetWindowHandle() returns false, so it is the foreground window....

Comment: @Hermetix I've managed to reproduce this behavior. Not pumping messaged before calling `SetCapture` makes cursor stuck at "waiting" state.

Comment: @Hermetix You can call it on the same spot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158096/discussion-between-hermetix-and-vtt).